# Grafana on ECS cluster return not allowed origin

Tags: grafana

Created **ECS** cluster let's call it **tools**.

tools cluster have 2 services:

```
sso-proxy

grafana - opensource
```

**Going through `sso-proxy` to get **`grafana`**.**

when trying to enter credentials to `grafana` i got the following error:

[image: grafana]

When `incognito` mode the login working for the first time.

This is the **ECS logs:**

[image]

Please someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

Grafana must receive proper `Host` header in the request header. I guess your "sso-proxy" doesn't do that. You didn't provide reproducible example (why not, when you want to help), so it is only a guess.

Lazy and insecure workaround will be Grafana downgrade to version 8.3.4-, where CSRF fix for CVE-2022-21703 is not included.